# What happened to DRYS stock (went from $1 mil+ to $2.37)?

Tags: stocks

Check out the insane stock graph here (select 10 yrs): http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DRYS?p=DRYS

I am always looking for answers on stock's behavior, and I can't find anything for DRYS (dryships) except for the fact that it is a shipping company. How and why would this ever be worth $1 mil+ and does anyone know why the stock has lost 99.999% of its value?

Comment: I don't think questions like this are a good fit for this site, though I don't think any of the close reasons fit well enough to use them. This isn't a personal finance question, it's just asking about a company's performance.

Comment: And - as far as not finding anything - read the news on that page you linked to.  Plenty of information as to what's going on.  Combination of collapse of the shipping industry and a billionaire who knows how to make money while his business is heading close to bankruptcy (remind you of anybody else?).

Comment: I think the question is more-opinion-based, so I'm voting to close on that basis.

Comment: Performing a quick google using terms "DRYS Kalani Investments" will give some results related to a couple recent events that have impacted the share price. Looking into DRYS' complete history would require a lot more digging.

Comment: Just saw this. I've been short since $1.1M, maybe it's time to cover that short?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

DRYS experienced a number of reverse share splits.  The company's share price was never over $1mm but since the company has now experienced a 1:25, 1:4, 1:15 and 1:8 reverse splits in the last 12 months, the historical prices are adjusted for the new share count.

Comment: Reverse splits.  They did those to keep the share price high enough to be listed on the NASDAQ.  That's not the reason for the massive collapse in share price for sure.

Comment: added the word reverse, @Joe, but this is the reason the past share price is illustrated as over $1mm

Comment: Numbers are just numbers, but the point is that is not related to the collapse: it's just related to the old number looking high.

Comment: This guy is asking why the share price went from $1mm to $2.  It was never $1mm, it's only illustrated as $1mm because of the drastic change in number of shares.

Comment: Sure, but you could just rephrase the question to "why does the share price go from $1000 to $0.0001", that's the real question he's asking.  The split is a piece of information but it's not the answer.

Comment: And part of the reason the share price changed so significantly is because there's a drastically different number of shares.  He's not asking about change in market cap, or change in enterprise value, he's asking about change in share price.  And in the last 12 months the number of shares has significantly changed, which impacts the share price.

Comment: `and does anyone know why the stock has lost 99.999% of its value?`  - that has 0 to do with the splits, except insomuch as the splits became necessary because of that loss.

Comment: What happened to DRYS stock (went from $1 mil+ to $2.37)?, it was never $1 mil+

Comment: I think the split is relevant information.  I just don't think it's a complete answer.  (I also don't think this question is a good fit for the site, regardless)

Comment: Yep, security analysis is never discussed on this site, ever.

Comment: "do my research for me" is not a good fit for this site, not securities of course.

Comment: I'm sure this thing popped up on some stupid stock screener and the 7 figure share price prompted this question.  If this was a $130/share company that fell to $0.00019 this question wouldn't exist.